# Reading html inside bootstrap table td tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found this bootstrap table : 
https://codepen.io/damasco491/pen/xMgqXN

The problem is that the **td tag** doesn't allow the HTML, ex:

```
<td><input type="text"/></td>
```

The result is showing the HTML as text : 
It should be resolved in the javascript bootstrap file ?

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

TO solve this there is an option to allow HTMl in bootstrap table, you need to add-

> data-escape="false"

in table tag like this -

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-filter-control="true" data-show-export="true"
        data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-escape="false" class="table-responsive">
```

Hop this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's resolved! 

Also, when I add a function to the table, any function, editing table or anything else I got the same error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**" Any help?